# Web application not creating in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

When I click on create new web application in central admin it's throwing below error.

[image]

I created web application through STSADM command, It created web application but there are no files in IIS Virtual Directory. so the site is not loading.

Please help me with this error ASAP.

**Edited Update**

I restarted all services, and also restarted web front end Server, still issue exist. I also ran **SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard** and it showed successfully completed, then restarted server still the issue exist.

Please help on this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with your Application Pool, see this post as a possible answer: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f2ccca2f-2448-498f-8ee5-506f2c19f1ae/moss2007-cannot-create-new-web-application-extend-is-ok-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance?forum=sharepointadminlegacy